# How to remove subsets and duplicates of lists from a list?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I have a class called MyObject

```
public class MyObject {
    private int id;
    ...
}
```

And a List of Lists called myList containing instances of MyObject:

```
List<List<MyObject>> myList;
```

I need to write a method that removes all subsets and duplicates that are present in that list, compared against the same List.
For example if there is a List with the IDs:

```
4 10 12
```

And another List with the IDs:

```
4 12
```

I need that List removed. However something like:

```
2 4 12
```

should not be removed.

I've seen different solutions but I wasn't able to make them work for my case. Can someone help?

Comment: What if your second list contained a 2?  Would you keep both lists?  You need to include more diverse examples.

Comment: @WJS A list should only be removed if all of its elements are in another list

Comment: Given your description, your example seems wrong. A list {4,12} is not a sublist of {4,10,12}, and so should not be removed at all. A list {4,10}, however, would be a sublist of {4,10,12}. Also, probably start by "not using List" but writing a proper data structure that can _ingest_ lists, but stores a single sequence internally, with a list of start-and-length records that can be used to _generate_ the lists that were stored. Now you can check if a new sequence is anywhere in your master sequence, and if it is, whether its storage record would falls inside one that you already have.

Comment: I think you may be confusing sublists with subsequences.  The elements.of a sublist  are contiguous.  Subsequences are not.

Comment: Does a list may have duplicate entries? Meaning: is `3 3 44 12 12` a valid list? Next, is the sequence of the entries relevant? Meaning: is `3 4 5` equal to `5 4 3` and `4 3 5`? Are the entries always sorted?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more efficient ways to do this but this seems to work. I chose to demonstrate it with lists of `ints` but it can easily be adapted to work with a class of  objects as long as the class overrides the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

- First, allocate a list to store the lists to be removed.
- Then sort the lists by length in reverse order. This ensures that only larger lists will check to see if they contain smaller lists.
- With a nested loop, iterate over both lists, starting the inner loop index one ahead of the outer loop (no need to see if a list contains itself).
- Now compare the two lists.  If containment is true, the add that list to the list of those to remove.
- when done, remove the duplicate lists

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
  List.of(7),
  List.of(3,7),
  List.of(10),
  List.of(3,2,1),
  List.of(1,2,3,8,9),
  List.of(1,2,9),
  List.of(1,2,8,9),
  List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  List.of(1,2,45)));

List<List<Integer>> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
lists.sort(Comparator.comparing(List::size, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
for(int i = 0; i < lists.size()-1; i++) {
    List<Integer> next = lists.get(i);
    for (int k = i+1; k < lists.size(); k++) {
        
        List<Integer> current = lists.get(k);
        
        if (!toBeRemoved.contains(current) && next.containsAll(current)) {
            toBeRemoved.add(lists.get(k));              
        }
    }
}
lists.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
System.out.println(lists);
```

prints

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8, 9], [1, 2, 45], [3, 7], [10]]
```

I tried a few alternatives such as using nested iterators to be able to remove the lists as they are discovered but I was getting `ConcurrentModification` exceptions.  Same was true when using hybrid solutions with iterators and loops.

**Eliminating the sort**

Here is another similar algorithm.

- the loops both go from 0 to the size of the list.
- Thus a set is used to hold the `toBeRemoved` items.  The set is consulted before checking to see if the list has already been removed and sets are more efficient for this operation.
- A check must also be done to ensure a list isn't being checked against itself.  Otherwise it would be removed as would others.
- Everything else is the same.

```
Set<List<Integer>> toBeRemoved = new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    List<Integer> next = lists.get(i);
    for (int k = 0; k < lists.size(); k++) {
        
        List<Integer> current = lists.get(k);
        if (current == next) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!toBeRemoved.contains(current) && next.containsAll(current)) {
            toBeRemoved.add(lists.get(k));              
        }
    }
}
lists.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
```